# Programmatically add cart content to new order (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i'm trying to do 2 simple steps: 
1) create an order
2) Getting the user cart content to be written into that order.

Step 1 is all good, But step 2 is not really going for me.

Trying to use the WC_Checkout::create_order_line_items method (2 params: an order object, and a cart object).

```
$order = wc_create_order();
$cart = WC()->cart;
WC()->checkout->create_order_line_items($order, $cart);
```

The order is created, but it won't add nothing to the item list.
Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting the cart correctly, try this:

```
WC()->cart->get_cart();
```